# Extract blocks of numbers from array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, cell-array

I have a vector and I would like to extract all the blocks from it:

```
x = [1 1 1 4 4 5 5 4 6 1 2 4 4 4 9 8 4 4 4 4]
```

so that I will get vectors or a cell containing the blocks:

```
[1 1 1], [4 4], [5 5], [4], [6], [1], [2], [4 4 4], [9], [8], [4 4 4 4]
```

Is there an efficient way to do it without using for loops? Thanks!

Comment: what is inefficient about for loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) with a custom [anonymous function](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html):

```
y = accumarray(cumsum([true; diff(x(:))~=0]), x(:), [], @(x) {x.'}).';
```

This gives a cell array of vectors. In your example,

```
x = [1 1 1 4 4 5 5 4 6 1 2 4 4 4 9 8 4 4 4 4];
```

the result is

```
y{1} =
     1     1     1
y{2} =
     4     4
y{3} =
     5     5
y{4} =
     4
y{5} =
     6
y{6} =
     1
y{7} =
     2
y{8} =
     4     4     4
y{9} =
     9
y{10} =
     8
y{11} =
     4     4     4     4
```

Answer (score 0):

For loops aint as slow as you might think, especially not in more recent Matlab versions and especially not in our case. Maybe this will help

```
x = [1 1 1 4 4 5 5 4 6 1 2 4 4 4 9 8 4 4 4 4];

breakIdx = [0, find(diff(x)), length(x)];
groups = mat2cell(x,1,diff(breakIdx));
```

We find the groups by applying `diff(x)` and we get the group indices with `find()`. Then it's just a matter of moving the groups into the resulting cell `groups`.

There's very little edge case checks here so I recommend you add that.

Comment: you can use `groups=mat2cell(x,1,diff(breakIdx));` to replace the for loop in your code, but that would only help readabilty as `mat2cell()` itself uses that loop.

Comment: Great comment @Finn ! `mat2cell` makes it much cleaner :).

Answer (score 0):

If holding all blocks in a cell array is not so important, but ruther the full information about them, you can use this code:

```
x = [1 1 1 4 4 5 5 4 6 1 2 4 4 4 9 8 4 4 4 4];
elements = x(diff([0 x])~=0);
block_size = accumarray(cumsum(diff([0 x])~=0).',1).';
blocks = [elements; block_size];
```

to get a 2-row matrix with the element on the first row, and the block size on the second:

```
blocks =
     1     4     5     4     6     1     2     4     9     8     4
     3     2     2     1     1     1     1     3     1     1     4
```

Then define a function to create those blocks by need:

```
getBlock = @(k) ones(1,blocks(2,k))*blocks(1,k);
```

and call it with the number of block you want:

```
getBlock(8)
```

to get:

```
ans =
     4     4     4
```